# DevExpress unable to Set the Max Value in Y axis like 0k, 50k, 100k. I have tried but cannot do it with the same expected , it change depends on data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

DevExpress unable to  Set the Max Value in Y axis like 0k, 50k, 100k. I have tried but cannot do it with the same expected , it changes depends on data.

Can any devexpress developers can help me on this ....
[Expected  y-axis values in 0k, 50k, 100k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRQcW.png)

Awaiting for any response...

I am trying to set the Y axis for my chart in devExpress in my specification as 0k, 50k, 100k but cannot able  to do it. it changes as per the value from the DB. Cannot able to Set Yaxis value as static